# "Namespace" collision detection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

Does the JavaScript frameworks which mimics namespaces like jQuery makes some namespace collision detection ? If not should I manage it myself ?

If yes what prevents such framework to detect such collision themselves ?

Comment: I don't have the time to explain this myself, but have a look at Paul Irish' video [10 Things I Learned from the jQuery Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_qE1iAmjFg#t=12m35) where he talks about `noConflict`. Also see his [own blog](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) for further links and comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript namespaces are normally mimicked by using objects and closures, and often initialized with a self-invoking function:

```
var myNamespace = (function () {
   var _name = 'Bob';

   return {
      somePublicMethod: function () {
         return 'Hello, ' + _name;
      }
   };
})();

alert(myNamespace.somePublicMethod());
```

Unfortunately if you redefine the namespace variable, there's no warning for that. What you could really do is to check if the namespace variable has already been defined, and throw an exception or raise an error if it was:

```
if (typeof myNamespace !== 'undefined') {
    var myNamespace = (function () {
        // ...
    })();
}
else {
    throw new Error("Whoops! myNamespace already exists.");
}
```

Comment: Isn't this actually backwards?   Wouldn't you check for namespace === 'undefined' and then define it, else throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

Consider coming up with a development standard where entire team agrees on how you will call your namespaces. Also I found it useful reviewing any changes to data structure or namespaces before actually implementing them.

Comment: But this is not possible if your framework is distributed worldwide like jquery.